# Spring boot JWT setExpiration not working

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'm setting the setExpiration, but my app still expires in less than 1h. I'm using springboot JWT with redis.

`private long EXPIRATIONTIME = 10512011520l; // 4 month`

`String JWT = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(auth.getPrincipal().toString())
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                .compact();`

Answer (score 1):

try to add this:

```
.setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS * 1000))
```

but consider that expiration time is in milli second and you have to multiply by 1000